# How to align two rows with different number of columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to line up 2 rows with a different number of columns. The first row has 11 columns. The second row has 6 columns. Six of the top row columns need to line up with the 6 bottom row columns and be responsive.

I have tried padding on the columns, the elements themselves and the row. I still can't make it line up.

Any suggestions? I looked at flexbox but am unsure of how that would work.

[image]

Comment: How are the rows and columns structured? It might help to include the relevant HTML and CSS as a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: you mean 6 columns out of the 11 columns in the first row should align with 6 out of 6 rows in your second row?

Comment: Use flex or table layout. Define "responsive". More cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I'm assuming that you're able to forcibly set the width of these elements to be one consistent value. I'm also assuming that you want the first 6 of the top row to be aligned with the first 6 of the bottom row, and so on.

One solution is to add empty items to the bottom row with the same width as the other bottom-row elements. Then, using flexbox to space out each element with `justify-content: space-between;`. This will let them have spacing when the window is large enough for that (assuming that's the kind of responsive you want).

Here's a JSFiddle demonstrating that:
https://jsfiddle.net/a1q79rjk/2/

Answer (score 1):

CSS-Grid can so that:

```css
.row {
  display: grid;
  margin-bottom: .25em;
}

.top,
.bottom {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 35px 1fr 35px 1fr 35px 1fr 35px 1fr 35px 1fr
}

.item,
.box {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-left: 1px solid green;
  border-right: 1px solid green;
}

.item:nth-child(2n-1) {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.box {
  background: lightblue;
}

.box:nth-child(1) {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: 3;
}

.box:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column: 5
}

.box:nth-child(4) {
  grid-column: 7
}

.box:nth-child(5) {
  grid-column: 9
}

.box:nth-child(6) {
  grid-column: 11
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row top">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">&rarr;</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">&rarr;</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">&rarr;</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">&rarr;</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">&rarr;</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row bottom">
    <div class="box">box1</div>
    <div class="box">box2</div>
    <div class="box">box3</div>
    <div class="box">box4</div>
    <div class="box">box5</div>
    <div class="box">box6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why you have those spaces in the first place:

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box; padding:0; margin:0;
}
table{
  table-layout:fixed; border-collapse:collapse; width:100%; background:#ccc;
}
table>tbody>tr>*{
  height:50px; border:1px solid #000; text-align:center;
}
table+table>tbody>tr>*{
  border-top:0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><th>img 1</th><th>space 1</th><th>img 2</th><th>space 2</th><th>img 3</th><th>space 3</th><th>img 4</th><th>space 4</th><th>img 5</th><th>space 5</th><th>img 6</th></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>text 1</td><td>text 2</td><td>text 3</td><td>text 4</td><td>text 5</td><td>text 6</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```